# How to extract floating point value from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to extract the value "-1.23" from the following string using JS regex?

```
"hello-sdvf-1.23 23 everybody 4"
```

this code extracts only "-1"

```
("hello-sdvf-1.23 23 everybody 4").match(/[-]\d+|\d+/)[0];
```

Comment: `'hello-sdvf-1,123.23 23 everybody 4'.match(/-?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*?\.\d+/g)[0].replace(/,/g,'')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the pattern to match decimal part also.

```
string.match(/-?\d+\.\d+/)
```

Comment: how to ignore the proceeding commas?
eg: ("hello-sdvf-1,123.23 23 everybody 4").match(/[-]\d+|\d+/)[0];
should return "-1123.23"

Comment: then you need to use replace function.

Comment: try `alert(s.match(/-?\d+(?:,\d+)*\.\d+)/)[0].replace(',', ''));`

Comment: how get numbers like "1,123.02"

Comment: cannot find the solution

Comment: ask this as a new question with detailed explanation.